# execution reverted 0x contract on goerli for swap but every transaction fails while giving me the error? although tx object is fine

Tags: 0x

i am getting the same error on every transaction and its on goelri network, furthermore not supoorting much of pairs. Attaching the image for reference
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like any calls have succeeded to that contract since migrate was called over a year ago.

Looking at their documentation seems like this is the goerli address: 0xf91bb752490473b8342a3e964e855b9f9a2a668e

> Ethereum Mainnet (Chain ID: 1) ExchangeProxy:
> 0xdef1c0ded9bec7f1a1670819833240f027b25eff ... Goerli Testnet (Chain
> ID: 5) ExchangeProxy: 0xf91bb752490473b8342a3e964e855b9f9a2a668e

https://0x.org/docs/developer-resources/contract-addresses

Simulating your data to that address, the function sig is found and call is made, though it failed at a later stage with "revertWithData", "OrderNotFillableError".

You should be able to work through the issues using that contract address.